# Updating Columns from columns in same table

Tags: t-sql

I wanted to update a password field for multiple rows in a table with the last four digits of a phone number field within the same table.

Not sure how to set this up?  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    passColumn = RIGHT(phoneColumn, 4)
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that simple haha.  Thanks for that.  I was over thinking this query setup.

Comment: The only "curveball" that I've run into that might require some extra precaution is that sometimes columns storing phone numbers, if not pattern-validated, and if large enough, sometimes end with, say, "x345" to show an extension.

Comment: @tim, have to agree with you. Depending on the data integrity built into the database, you nay have a lot of garbage in this field. I've seen (000)000-0000 and "don't call' and 757-789-0980; 672-567-8999 (made up numbers) or 567-6789-09087 home and many more not real phone number variants.